# creating strings inside a for each loop? or creat them outside, use inside?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have the following code below and was lookign to clean it up, but am not sure if it needs clean up or not.

```
foreach (SearchResult sr in mySrchColl)
{
    string strValIn = sr.Properties["in"][0].ToString();
    string strValOut= sr.Properties["out"][0].ToString();
}
```

do i change this to something like this:

```
string strValIn = "";
string strValOut= "";

foreach (SearchResult sr in mySrchColl)
            {
                strValIn = sr.Properties["in"][0].ToString();
                strValOut= sr.Properties["out"][0].ToString();
}
```

whats the difference or are these two identical?

Comment: I think you must be missing some code in your example. What are you going to do with those strings?

Comment: And what is the point of that code anyway?  You may as well just assign the last element.

Comment: i use the string variables later in a call to a function that takes 10 params, so instead of having them all inline i could read what they are using meaningful variable names...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first code segment, the variables will be accessible only within the loop. In the second code segment, they can be accessed outside the loop. This is known as [Programming Scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29)

Comment: what about the system reclaiming resources for the variables? if the loop goes on for 1000 times will it matter? i think the resources reclamation will occur after each loop -am i correct?

Comment: According to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/d43aaba5-a58b-4610-bea4-5bc5d6741f98 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407255/difference-between-declaring-variables-before-or-in-loop, it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

They compile down to the same IL...no performance difference. It would only be readability; if only used in the foreach...keep the declaration in there.

Answer (score 1):

[Difference between declaring variables before or in loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407255/difference-between-declaring-variables-before-or-in-loop)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't *capture* the variables into a lambda / anon method it won't make any difference. Inside is arguably cleaner.

As a side note; even if you *declare* them outside; you don't need to *initialize* it there; the following is valid:

```
string s;
foreach(...) {
    s = ...
}
```

I would still declare inside though :)

Answer (score 0):

In dotnet strings are immutable, so both of the example codes are going to create new objects and assign them to the 2 variables. As such if you are not using those 2 variables outside the foreach loop there isnt going to be much difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second one is better. Because in first one, you are creating `reference` and `object of string` in loop...whereas in second case , you are just creating ' object of string' and references are just changing...