# Should define variables in the "for" loop, or out side of "for" loop

Tags: android

Sometimes some guys tell, I'd better to define variables in the "for" loop, and other times some guys tell me I should define outside of "for" loop.
I am very confused.

Could some guys tell me which is better when it comes to Android?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Look at http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ddevore/archive/2006/08/declare_variabl.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407255/difference-between-declaring-variables-before-or-in-loop

Comment: You can take reference of this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407255/difference-between-declaring-variables-before-or-in-loop

Answer (score 0):

Defining is the part where you give a value to a variable. It shouls be done in the proper scope. If you value depends on the iteration, then, obviously, it has to be done inside the loop. If it doesn't, there is no reason to reassign the value at every turn. See :

```
for (A a : B) {
    c = "constant"
}
```

doesn't make sense.

However, *declaration* can be discussed. It can be placed outside as it allocates the pointer memory only once, but it can be placed inside if it has a limited scope and don't need to exist outside the loop.