# Upload Multiple Files (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, file-upload, stringbuilder

I'm trying to upload multiple files with VB.Net code but have had no success. I end up with only one file on the webserver when there is more than one file (`FileExists` is `True` for multiple elements). If I finish the loop in other some place, it raises an exception.

This is my code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Sub upload()
    Dim filepath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "C:\i.bmp")
    Dim filepath2 As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "C:\i.txt")
    Dim url As String = "http://localhost/SEND/MultUp.php"

    Dim Element As Object
    Dim sNames(0 To 3) As String 'Array declaration

    sNames(0) = filepath2
    sNames(1) = ""
    sNames(2) = ""
    sNames(3) = filepath

    Dim boundary As String = IO.Path.GetRandomFileName
    Dim header As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    For Each Element In sNames 'Roaming all elements of array
        If File.Exists(Element) Then
            header.AppendLine("--" & boundary)
            header.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""files[]"";")
            header.AppendFormat("filename=""{0}""", IO.Path.GetFileName(Element))
            header.AppendLine()
            header.AppendLine("Content-Type: application/octet-stream")
            header.AppendLine()

            Dim headerbytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header.ToString)
            Dim endboundarybytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vbNewLine & "--" & boundary & "--" & vbNewLine)

            Dim req As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
            req.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & boundary
            req.ContentLength = headerbytes.Length + New IO.FileInfo(Element).Length + endboundarybytes.Length
            req.Method = "POST"

            Dim s As IO.Stream = req.GetRequestStream
            s.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length)
            Dim filebytes() As Byte = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(Element)
            s.Write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length)
            s.Write(endboundarybytes, 0, endboundarybytes.Length)
            s.Close()

            header.clear() 'this was missing in my original source code
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You aren't emptying your StringBuilder as far as I can see, so that may be an issue.

Comment: Very good your suggestion @jmcilhinney! Adding => header.Clear() before => End If works fine now. Thank you very much.

Comment: on the server side, have you got a loop set up to go through th multiple Form1.Requests?

Comment: Yes @Frank_Vr! I have a php script with a correct configuration for this make by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Full credit to [jmcilhinney's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057744/upload-multiple-files-vb-net#comment33446886_22057744):

The originally posted code was missing the `header.clear()` call. Therefore, as multiple elements were processed, the `header` variable continued to append lines.

A better practice would be to declare the `header` StringBuilder variable within the `For Each` loop. It makes it [easier to maintain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407255/difference-between-declaring-variables-before-or-in-loop), and the compiler should optimize it either way. Since `header` isn't used outside the loop, it should be used in the narrowest scope.