# How do I check assembly output of Java code?

Tags: java, assembly, jvm, jit, jvm-hotspot

I found this question that answered it for C++:

[How do you get assembler output from C/C++ source in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc)

Comment: Java doesn't output assembly code.

Comment: Oh, it does indeed :). Just have a look at https://www.beyondjava.net/blog/java-programmers-guide-assembler-language/ or my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java uses bytecode. The most similar would be [`javap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html), per the linked Oracle documentation, *the **javap** command disassembles one or more class files. Its output depends on the options used.*

```
package com.stackoverflow;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

If I compile that to `Main.class` and then run `javap -v Main.class` I get

```
Classfile /home/efrisch/workspace/StackOverflow/bin/com/stackoverflow/Main.class
  Last modified Jun 18, 2015; size 553 bytes
  MD5 checksum de4f987e783aa0f145e7245269504028
  Compiled from "Main.java"
class com.stackoverflow.Main
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Class              #2             // com/stackoverflow/Main
   #2 = Utf8               com/stackoverflow/Main
   #3 = Class              #4             // java/lang/Object
   #4 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
   #5 = Utf8               <init>
   #6 = Utf8               ()V
   #7 = Utf8               Code
   #8 = Methodref          #3.#9          // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #9 = NameAndType        #5:#6          // "<init>":()V
  #10 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #11 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #12 = Utf8               this
  #13 = Utf8               Lcom/stackoverflow/Main;
  #14 = Utf8               main
  #15 = Utf8               ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #16 = Fieldref           #17.#19        // java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  #17 = Class              #18            // java/lang/System
  #18 = Utf8               java/lang/System
  #19 = NameAndType        #20:#21        // out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  #20 = Utf8               out
  #21 = Utf8               Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  #22 = String             #23            // Hello, World!
  #23 = Utf8               Hello, World!
  #24 = Methodref          #25.#27        // java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #25 = Class              #26            // java/io/PrintStream
  #26 = Utf8               java/io/PrintStream
  #27 = NameAndType        #28:#29        // println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #28 = Utf8               println
  #29 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #30 = Utf8               args
  #31 = Utf8               [Ljava/lang/String;
  #32 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #33 = Utf8               Main.java
{
  com.stackoverflow.Main();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags:
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 3: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  this   Lcom/stackoverflow/Main;

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: getstatic     #16                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
         3: ldc           #22                 // String Hello, World!
         5: invokevirtual #24                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
         8: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 5: 0
        line 6: 8
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       9     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
}
SourceFile: "Main.java"
```

Answer (score 21):

Java uses both bytecode and <s>assembly language</s> machine code. It's a two-step process. The first step is to compile the Java source code to bytecode, as @elliott-frisch pointed out. At runtime, the JVM watches which parts of the program are used a lot. If a method "runs hot", it's compiled to machine code. That, in turn, is a multi-step process itself, including many optimizations and replacing fast code with even faster code. I've described this in [BeyondJava.net](https://www.beyondjava.net/blog/java-programmers-guide-assembler-language/) several years ago.

If you can spare 45 minutes, I also recommend watching the talk of Charles Nutter. ["Down the rabbit hole"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBKVdJph_oQ) is a great introduction to how Java compiles to assembly language.

As for your question: you have to add some parameters to the command starting the application:

```
javaw.exe -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly Adder
```

You also have to download a special DLL and store it in the jre folder. Also see [Chris Newlands article](https://www.chrisnewland.com/updated-instructions-for-building-hsdis-on-osx-417) on how to compile this file for OS X.

Comment: There's already a [How to see JIT-compiled code in JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503479/how-to-see-jit-compiled-code-in-jvm) Q&A which suggests the same options.

Comment: It doesn't compile anything to assembly code. It goes straight to machine code. You can get a printable output in assembly but that's a byproduct of the printing process. Java does not waste its time running an assembler.

Comment: You're right. I've corrected the text. In my mind assembly code and machine code are sort of synonyms, because when I'm programming on the machine code level, I'm using an assembler.