# Breaking up methods leading to more operations

Tags: javascript, class, oop, dry, solid-principles

Breaking up methods/functions to do one thing only  is considered a good practice as it leads to more maintainable and readable code but it increase number of operations in many cases . How to achieve both ie. optimum number of operations while still keeping readability/maintainability  ?

As illustrated in this dummy example . I want to find count of `J`s in a string but also want to check if addition of all positive integers is `even` or `odd` . Two separate methods for these 2 different tasks leads to excellent readability but increases number of operations by `n` where `n` is size of input string . Combining them in a method leads to very low readability but decreases number of operations.

```
class UserText{ 
    constructor(userProvidedText){
     this.content = userProvidedText;
    }
    _findCharCount(char){
      let count = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.content.length; i++) {
        if (this.content[i] === char) {
          count++;
        }
    }   
    return count
    }

    _isDigit(char) {
        return !isNaN(parseInt(char));
      }

    // Excellent Readability and maintainability 
    findLetterCount(char){
        return this._findCharCount(char)
        }
    
    // Excellent Readability and maintainability 
    CheckIfDigitsAdditionEven(){ 
        let count = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.content.length; i++) {
          console.log(this.content[i])
          if (!this._isDigit(this.content[i])){ 
            continue
          }
          count+=parseInt(this.content[i]); 
        }   
        if (count % 2 === 0){ 
            return true
        } 
        return false
    }

    // Combining functionalities in 1 function . Not readable. Not maintainable But time complexity is decreased. 
    CheckIfDigitsAdditionEvenAndCountLetter(char){ 
        let count1 = 0;
        let count2 = 0;

        let res1 = false;

        for (let i = 0; i < this.content.length; i++) {
          if (this.content[i] === char) {
            count2++;
          }
          if (this._isDigit(this.content[i])){ 
            count1+=parseInt(this.content[i]); 
          }
        }   
        if (count1 % 2 === 0){ 
            res1 = true
        } 
        return [res1, count2]

    }
}
```

```
ut = new UserText("SOME..STRING..12311.HHIIJJJJKKKLL ")

/*
Breaking up functions and using them one at a time . One method , one purpose.. 
Maintainable and readable but iterates by 2n.  
*/

JCount=ut.findLetterCount("J") 
evenCheck=ut.CheckIfDigitsAdditionEven()


/*
Using 1 function for the task  . One method , multi-purposed.. 
Maintainable and readable is very low but  iterates by "n" only .  
*/

cr=ut.CheckIfDigitsAdditionEvenAndCountLetter("J")
```

```
// Some custom logic here . 
console.log(JCount, evenCheck)
console.log(cr[0], cr[1])
```

Comment: "*but it increase time complexity in many cases*" it doesn't though. If you're refactoring to DRY your code you should end up with the code doing the same operations but maybe more calls linking the different sections. If you end up with the code doing *more operations* as in the complexity changes, you've done something wrong.

Comment: *time complexity*: I think you are confusing time complexity with the actual time to run your code. Two different concepts. Code that has a linear time complexity, given input size , could take one millisecond or 10 hours. That's not related to time complexity. In your example code the time complexity didn't change.

Comment: @trincot also, OP seems to believe `O(2n)` and `O(n)` are different time complexities. Whereas they are the same - complexity analysis drops all constants and only measures the growth rate, after all. Actually demonstrated by OP since they didn't calculate the complexity of their code with the other constant factors, which would be some form of `O(a*n + b)` and the `b` was dropped, but `a` wasn't.

Comment: My point was that the for loop is being run twice VS once(most optimum solution) .  What's the correct terminology that I should use instead of "time complexity" . I will edit it accordingly .

Comment: Also, I've been looking at this code and I don't think I'd agree on the "Excellent Readability and maintainability" in both places. The `findJs()` seems needlessly specific - if you want to check the entire alphabet, that'd be 26 methods. `_findCharCount()` is OK, though. `CheckIfDigitsAdditionEven()` does multiple things. Which you can tell from the name. It's finding all digits, then also summing them but also checking if the sum is even.

Comment: What's also notable is that `CheckIfDigitsAdditionEvenAndCountJs()` *doesn't* work like the other two methods, since it will try to find the count *or* sum of characters, depending on if the argument passed in is a numeric string or not. But it will count `"J"` in the usage example, which the other code doesn't do. The other code doesn't even take parameters, so it will sum all numeric strings. The example is just all over the place.

Comment: @VLAZ Passing arguments is not the crux of my question . That can always be edited to` findLetterCount("J")` and rename the combined one as  `CheckIfDigitsAdditionEvenAndCountLetter`

Comment: I was talking about your example and critiquing how it didn't serve its purpose, since it doesn't showcase SOLID vs non-SOLID code. It showed some code which it claimed was supposed to be "good" to contrast with "worse but more efficient" code. However, the first code wasn't good, either. The example doesn't even seem to have a clear purpose as it does two different things. If you want to find the sum of a given numeric character as a parameter, you don't even need the "worse" code, since you can do .`_findCharCount(num) * num` which is just going over the array once.

Comment: @VLAZ That's not what I want to do . I want to sum all the digits in a string and return True if the addition is even . I accept rest of the critique and have eddited the code .

Comment: @VLAZ  I need to read more about time complexity . I might have got it wrong . I will make that edit also . The crux of my question still stands , I am running 2 for loops instead of 1 in pursuit of readability.

Comment: Your assumption that 2 loops is slower than one is not necessarily correct https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952494/why-are-two-separate-loops-faster-than-one

Comment: @shadow but the cux of my point stands *that's not good code*. You are not doing it SOLID, what you have is just slightly altered. You've just extracted the two operations you want to do in two methods which you call twice. Yes, that's less optimal. No, that's not what the end goal is. Extract each operation you want to do at each iteration then have the class accept them as strategies. Here is a quick example: https://jsbin.com/yejirudezo/1/edit?js,console While not perfect (too much code, can be more generic) it's just a first draft at what the code should look like.

Comment: Also, the code does end up too verbose because you're trying to do this purely OO, for some reason. I followed suit almost but it's really much easier to accept callbacks instead of having multiple subclasses for a strategy. Even Java figured this out, C# as well.

Comment: @VLAZ Nicely done ! That's very SOLID and DRY but like you said it's too verbose. 
`CharacterExtractor` , `NumericExtractor` can be removed and `accept` method  can be embedded directly  in `CountingAggregator` , `IntegerSummingAggregator` , `IsEvenDecorator` . Maybe get rid of the abstract classes as well . What do you think of that scheme? 

Can you please give me a good example using callbacks . Thanks .

Comment: @VLAZ Can you please give me a good implementation of the same example using callbacks. Also what do you think about the scheme in my previous comment ? Do you think it strikes a good balance between code length and good software design while also solving our purpose of limiting the no. of operations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thinking about performance issues while designing the model is good, but *Premature Optimization* should be avoided.

Second, the OP's code in my opinion is neither clean/lean nor maintainable, where the OP claims it to be. And the implementation with all the pseudo-privately annotated prototype methods already starts as a big mess.

Third, the OP's `CheckIfDigitsAdditionEvenAndCountLetter` method intermingles two tasks which anyhow have to be implemented each separately ... e.g. as `hasEvenTotalDigitCount` and `getTotalLetterCountFor`.

Thus said, the OP should write a lot of helper/utility functions which each do one thing a time. These helpers then get re/used by the very few and only really necessary methods, the OP wants the model to feature.

A much better readable, maintainable version of what the OP did provide could look like the following example code ...

```js
// e.g. ... `UserText` module with ...
//
//  - locally scoped helper functions
//  - and a single class export.
// 
//  - each helper function might/should
//    get exported as well for testing.

function isEven(value) {
  return (value % 2 === 0);
}

function isDigit(value) {
  return (/^\p{N}$/u).test(String(value));
}
function isLetter(value) {
  return (/^\p{L}$/u).test(String(value));
}

function getTotalDigitCount(text) {
  return text.match(/\p{N}/gu).length;
}
function getTotalLetterCount(text) {
  return text.match(/\p{L}/gu).length;
}

function getTotalMatchCount(text, query) {
  return text.match(
    RegExp(
      query.replace(/[/\-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'g'
    )
  )?.length ?? 0;
}

/*export */class UserText{
  #text;

  constructor(value) {
    // - always ensure a protected string value.
    this.#text = String(value);
  }
  get value() {
    // - helps ensuring the immutability of
    //   the initially passed user text value.
    return this.#text;
  }

  getTotalDigitCountFor(value) {
    value = String(value);

    return isDigit(value) ? getTotalMatchCount(this.#text, value) : 0;
  }
  getTotalLetterCountFor(value) {
    value = String(value);

    return isLetter(value) ? getTotalMatchCount(this.#text, value) : 0;
  }

  hasEvenTotalDigitCount() {
    const totalCount = getTotalDigitCount(this.#text);

    return (totalCount !== 0) && isEven(totalCount);
  }
  hasEvenTotalLetterCount() {
    const totalCount = getTotalLetterCount(this.#text);

    return (totalCount !== 0) && isEven(totalCount);
  }
}
// end of `UserText` module.



// e.g.

/* import { UserText } from './UserText.js'; */
const userText = new UserText("SOME..STRING..12311.HHIIJJJJKKKLL ");

const totalCountOfUpper_J = userText.getTotalLetterCountFor('J');
const hasEvenTotalDigitCount = userText.hasEvenTotalDigitCount();

console.log({
  totalCountOfUpper_J,
  hasEvenTotalDigitCount,
});

// attempt of manipulating the text value.
userText.value = 'foo, bar, baz';

console.log({
  userText,
  'userText.value': userText.value,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit** according to the OP's comment ...*

> 1. *"Premature Optimization should be avoided."* Could you please expand ? What if I have a str which consumes 500MB in RAM . Now If I process it twice , my performance is going to take a big hit . Same issue If I have a 1MB string but the 2 operations are heavy . I will have to plan beforehand . 2. If I want to run `hasEvenTotalDigitCount()` and `getTotalLetterCountFor()` . We will be running 2 regex meaning 2 iterations of the same string instead of 1 , which is what my problem was in the first place . 3. I wanted check if addition of all digits was even not digit count

If there is a 500MB String in RAM, it depends on the target platform. A browser might not be the best environment for running an application which has such requirements whereas a highly performant node server environment might not even getting close to being in trouble.

In addition, taking into account the scenario described by the OP, the question arises whether a class based design like the one introduced with the original question does really suite the OP's needs.

But what could be done is the introduction of lazy computation and memoization techniques, in order do the heavy lifting only when it's needed and never twice for one and the same time consuming operation.

And of cause nothing prevents the OP from implementing a function which does all the necessary computation within a single full string iteration when there is no other option. But then again, the implementation of additional functionality which each computes just a fraction of it is entirely obsolete.

```js
// e.g. ... `UserText` module with ...
//
//  - locally scoped helper functions
//  - and a single class export.
// 
//  - each helper function might/should
//    get exported as well for testing.

function isEven(value) {
  return (value % 2 === 0);
}

function isDigit(value) {
  return (/^\p{N}$/u).test(String(value));
}
function isLetter(value) {
  return (/^\p{L}$/u).test(String(value));
}

function sumUp(summation, value) {
  return summation + Number(value);
}

function getDigits(text) {
  return text.match(/\p{N}/gu);
}
function getLetters(text) {
  return text.match(/\p{L}/gu);
}

function computeMatchCount(text, query) {
  return text.match(
    RegExp(
      query.replace(/[/\-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'g'
    )
  )?.length ?? 0;
}
function getMatchCount(text, query, matchCountLookup) {
  // - lookup the `query` specifc, possibly already memoized match-count.
  matchCount = matchCountLookup.get(query) ?? null;

  if (matchCount === null) {
    // - compute and memoize the `query` specifc match-count.
    matchCount = computeMatchCount(text, query);

    matchCountLookup.set(query, matchCount);
  }
  return matchCount;
}

/*export */class UserText{
  #text;

  #digitSummation;
  #matchCountLookup = new Map;

  constructor(value) {
    // - always ensure a protected string value.
    this.#text = String(value);
  }
  get value() {
    // - helps ensuring the immutability of
    //   the initially passed user text value.
    return this.#text;
  }

  get digitSummation() {
    // - lazy computation and memoization.
    return (this.#digitSummation ??= getDigits(this.#text).reduce(sumUp, 0));
  }
  get isDigitSummationEven() {
    // - either uses the memoized `digitSummation` value or triggers its computation.
    return isEven(this.digitSummation);
  }

  getDigitCountFor(value) {
    value = String(value);

    return isDigit(value)
      ? getMatchCount(this.#text, value, this.#matchCountLookup)
      : 0;
  }
  getLetterCountFor(value) {
    value = String(value);

    return isLetter(value)
      ? getMatchCount(this.#text, value, this.#matchCountLookup)
      : 0;
  }
}
// end of `UserText` module.



// e.g.

/* import { UserText } from './UserText.js'; */

// - an around 10MB messuring test string.
const hugeTestString = Array
  .from(
    { length: 300_000 }, crypto.randomUUID.bind(crypto)
  )
  .join(' ');

console.log({
  'hugeTestString.length': hugeTestString.length,
});
const userText = new UserText(hugeTestString + ' SOME..STRING..12311.HHIIJJJJKKKLL ');

// attempt of manipulating the text value.
userText.value = 'foo, bar, baz';

console.log({
  userText,
  // 'userText.value': userText.value,
});

// - any of the next same operations will
//   each return an already memoized value.
const lower_a_count = userText.getLetterCountFor('a');
const lower_f_count = userText.getLetterCountFor('f');

const upper_J_count = userText.getLetterCountFor('J');
const upper_S_count = userText.getLetterCountFor('S');

const digit_7_count = userText.getDigitCountFor('7');
const digit_0_count = userText.getDigitCountFor('0');

console.log({
  lower_a_count,
  lower_f_count,

  upper_J_count,
  upper_S_count,

                 // - returns an already memoized value.
  digit_7_count: userText.getDigitCountFor('7'),

                 // - returns an already memoized value.
  digit_0_count: userText.getDigitCountFor('0'),

  digitSummation: userText.digitSummation,
  isDigitSummationEven: userText.isDigitSummationEven,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: 1. "Premature Optimization should be avoided." 
Could you please expand ? What if I have a str which consumes 500MB in RAM . Now If I process it twice , my performance is going to take a big hit . Same issue If I have a 1MB string but the 2 operations are heavy  . I will have to plan beforehand .
2.  If I want to run `hasEvenTotalDigitCount()` and `getTotalLetterCountFor()` . We will be running 2 regex meaning 2 iterations of the same string instead of 1 , which is what my problem was in the first place . 
3. I wanted check if addition of all digits was even not digit count

Comment: @shadow ... I did edit my answer according to your comment.