# Strange Out of Memory Exception

Tags: java, jersey, out-of-memory, tomcat6

We are seeing a very weird situation with our web app. It uses Tomcat 6 and the web service is implemented with Jersey. The service calls below are meant to return JSON data.

The following throws OOM exception:

```
http://mywebservices/get/some/data/for/1
http://mywebservices/get/some/more/data/for/12345
http://mywebservices/get/some/other/data/for/abc
```

But, the following works fine:

```
http://mywebservices/get/some/data/for/12345
http://mywebservices/get/some/more/data/for/1
```

These are just made up calls to show what is happening. We have real time monitoring services that show ~5 GB available memory for JVM. **We believe the OOM the Tomcat is throwing at us is a fake/incorrect response.** The funny thing is even for completely different web services, the stack trace shown on the browser remains the same. We are very sure we are seeing the trace that is totally irrelevant given the web service request. So we are figuring out if we actually have a leak.

Meantime, it would be great to know if anybody has encountered this before.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide any information from the stack trace as this might be useful?

Comment: Please post the stack trace. We'd also like to see the code that is executed when these resources are requested. What are your VM args ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Even for completely different web service requests, the stack trace remains the same on the browser. A bogus one. Will post the stack trace in a bit.

Comment: Have you attached a debugger and stopped it when the OOM Exception would get thrown? What was happening at that time?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker We are seeing this issue on our production boxes and are unable to reproduce them in our staging environment. We were just analyzing heap dumps so far. Will attach a debugger.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the inputs. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so we believe we have found the root cause for this issue. There was a leak indeed because of the usage of ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream.

Now ObjectOutputStream has a reset() method that can clear the references but there is nothing like that for the ObjectInputStream.

This link helped us:
[Java out of heap space during serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495155/java-heap-space-out-of-memory)