# Unexpected OutOfMemoryError when using ObjectInputStream#readUnshared()

Tags: java, out-of-memory, deserialization, objectinputstream

I am running into an OOM when reading a large number of objects from an `ObjectInputStream` with `readUnshared`. [MAT](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer) points at its internal handle table as the culprit, as does the OOM stack trace (at end of this post). By all accounts, this shouldn't be happening. Furthermore, whether or not the OOM occurs appears to depend on how the objects were *written* previously.

According to [this write-up on the topic](https://orenkishon.wordpress.com/2014/06/28/java-memory-leak-caused-by-objectinputstream/), `readUnshared` should solve the issue (as opposed to `readObject`) by not creating handle table entries during read (that write-up is how I discovered `writeUnshared` and `readUnshared`, which I previously had not noticed).

However, it appears from my own observations that `readObject` and `readUnshared` behave identically, and whether the OOM happens or not depends on if the objects were *written* with a [`reset()` after each write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7495214/61640) (it does *not* matter if `writeObject` vs `writeUnshared` was used, as I previously thought -- I was just tired when I first ran the tests). That is:

```
              writeObject   writeObject+reset   writeUnshared   writeUnshared+reset
readObject       OOM               OK               OOM                 OK
readUnshared     OOM               OK               OOM                 OK
```

So whether or not `readUnshared` has any effect *actually* seems to be completely dependent on how the object was *written*. This is surprising and unexpected to me. I did spend some time tracing through the [`readUnshared` code path](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/io/ObjectInputStream.java#ObjectInputStream.readUnshared%28%29) but, and granted it was late and I was tired, it wasn't apparent to me why it would still be using handle space and why it would depend on how the object was written (however, I now have an initial suspect although I have yet to confirm, described below).

From all of my research on the topic so far, it appears `writeObject` with `readUnshared` *should* work.

Here is the program I've been testing with:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class OOMTest {

    // This is the object we'll be reading and writing.
    static class TestObject implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    }

    static enum WriteMode {
        NORMAL,     // writeObject
        RESET,      // writeObject + reset each time
        UNSHARED,   // writeUnshared
        UNSHARED_RESET // writeUnshared + reset each time
    }

    // Write a bunch of objects.
    static void testWrite (WriteMode mode, String filename, int count) throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename)));
        out.reset();
        for (int n = 0; n < count; ++ n) {
            if (mode == WriteMode.NORMAL || mode == WriteMode.RESET)
                out.writeObject(new TestObject());
            if (mode == WriteMode.UNSHARED || mode == WriteMode.UNSHARED_RESET)
                out.writeUnshared(new TestObject());
            if (mode == WriteMode.RESET || mode == WriteMode.UNSHARED_RESET)
                out.reset();
            if (n % 1000 == 0)
                System.out.println(mode.toString() + ": " + n + " of " + count);
        }
        out.close();
    }

    static enum ReadMode {
        NORMAL,     // readObject
        UNSHARED    // readUnshared
    }

    // Read all the objects.
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    static void testRead (ReadMode mode, String filename) throws Exception {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                TestObject o;
                if (mode == ReadMode.NORMAL)
                    o = (TestObject)in.readObject();
                if (mode == ReadMode.UNSHARED)
                    o = (TestObject)in.readUnshared();
                //
                if ((++ count) % 1000 == 0)
                    System.out.println(mode + " (read): " + count);
            } catch (EOFException eof) {
                break;
            }
        }
        in.close();
    }

    // Do the test. Comment/uncomment as appropriate.
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        /* Note: For writes to succeed, VM heap size must be increased.
        testWrite(WriteMode.NORMAL, "test-writeObject.dat", 30_000_000);
        testWrite(WriteMode.RESET, "test-writeObject-with-reset.dat", 30_000_000);
        testWrite(WriteMode.UNSHARED, "test-writeUnshared.dat", 30_000_000);
        testWrite(WriteMode.UNSHARED_RESET, "test-writeUnshared-with-reset.dat", 30_000_000);
        */
        /* Note: For read demonstration of OOM, use default heap size. */
        testRead(ReadMode.UNSHARED, "test-writeObject.dat"); // Edit this line for different tests.
    }

}
```

Steps to recreate issue with that program:

1. Run the test program with the `testWrite`s uncommented (and `testRead` not called) with the heap size set high, so `writeObject` does not lead to OOM.
2. Run the test program a second time with `testRead` uncommented (and `testWrite` not called) with the default heap size.

To be clear: I'm not doing the writing and reading in the same JVM instance. My writes happen in a separate program from my reads. The test program above may be slightly misleading at first glance due to the fact that I crammed both the write and read tests into the same source.

Unfortunately, the real situation I'm in is I have a file containing a lot of objects written with `writeObject` (without `reset`), which will take quite some time to regenerate (on the order of days) (and also the `reset` makes the output files massive), so I'd like to avoid that if possible. On the other hand, I cannot currently read the file with `readObject`, even with the heap space cranked up to the maximum available on my system.

It's worth noting that in my real situation, I do not need the caching provided by the object stream handle tables.

So my questions are:

1. **All my research so far suggests no connection between `readUnshared`'s behavior and how the objects were written. What is going on here?**
2. **Is there some way I can avoid the OOM on read, given that the data was written with `writeObject` and no `reset`?**

I'm not entirely sure why `readUnshared` is failing to resolve the issue here.

I hope this is clear. I am running on empty here so may have typed strange words.

---

From [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733364/avoid-outofmemoryerror-with-writeobject-readunshared#comment72587140_42733464) on an answer below:

> If you're not calling `writeObject()` in the current instance of the JVM you should not be consuming memory by calling `readUnshared()`.

All my research shows the same, and yet, confusingly:

- Here is the OOM stack trace, pointing at `readUnshared`:

  ```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream$HandleTable.grow(ObjectInputStream.java:3464)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream$HandleTable.assign(ObjectInputStream.java:3271)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1789)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUnshared(ObjectInputStream.java:460)
  at OOMTest.testRead(OOMTest.java:40)
  at OOMTest.main(OOMTest.java:54)
  ```
- Here is a [video of it happening](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-ASZJEKsYI) (video recorded before recent test program edit, video is equivalent of `ReadMode.UNSHARED` and `WriteMode.NORMAL` in new test program).
- Here are [some test data files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3jvshkfi7yk3n1/tests.7z?dl=0), which contain 30,000,000 objects (compressed size is a tiny 360 KB but be warned it expands to a whopping 2.34 GB). There are four test files here, each generated with various combinations of `writeObject`/`writeUnshared` and `reset`. The read behavior is dependent only on how it was written and independent of `readObject` vs. `readUnshared`. Note that the `writeObject` vs `writeUnshared` data files are byte-for-byte identical, I can't decide if this is surprising or not.

---

I've been staring at the `ObjectInputStream` code [from here](http://grepcode.com/). My current suspect is [this line](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/io/ObjectInputStream.java#1769), present in 1.7 and 1.8:

```
ObjectStreamClass desc = readClassDesc(false);
```

Where that `boolean` parameter is `true` for unshared and `false` for normal. In all other cases the "unshared" flag is propagated through to other calls, but in that case it's hard-coded to `false`, thus causing handles to be added to the handle table when reading class descriptions for serialized objects even when `readUnshared` is used. AFAICT, this is the *only* occurrence of the unshared flag not being passed through to other methods, hence why I am focused on it.

This is in contrast to e.g. [this line](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/io/ObjectInputStream.java#1335) where the unshared flag *is* passed through to `readClassDesc`. (You can trace the call path from `readUnshared` to both of those lines if anybody wishes to dig in.)

However, I have not yet confirmed that any of this is significant, or reasoned why `false` is hard-coded there. This is just the current track I'm taking looking into this, it may prove meaningless.

Also, fwiw, `ObjectInputStream` does have a private method, `clear`, that clears the handle table. I did an experiment where I called that (via reflection) after every read, but it just broke everything, so that's a no-go.

Answer (score 2):

> However, it seems that if the objects were written using `writeObject()` rather than `writeUnshared()`, then `readUnshared()` does not decrease handle table usage.

That is correct. `readUnshared()` only decreases handle table usage attributable to `readObject()`. If you are in the same JVM that is using `writeObject()` rather than `writeUnshared()`, handle table usage attributable to `writeObject()` is not decreased by `readUnshared()`.

Comment: Hm. When you say "in the same JVM" do you mean the same instance? In my case, the objects were written by a separate program, I don't do `writeObject` and `readUnshared` in the same run. In the test program only one of `testWrite` and `testRead` should be uncommented and run at any given time. My serialized data file already exists prior to running the reads.

Comment: If you're not calling `writeObject()` in the current instance of the JVM you should not be consuming memory by calling `readUnshared()`.

Comment: That's what I'm saying! It shouldn't be happening. :) Yet, it does. I've added a stack trace to the question pointing at `readUnshared` as well as [video evidence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-ASZJEKsYI).

Comment: So I've made a pretty substantial edit to the question. I was tire when I ran those tests. It's not `writeObject` vs `writeUnshared` that makes the difference, it's whether or not I put a `reset` between writes. Same mystery (`readObject` vs `readUnshared` behave identically and depend only on write method), just different observations.

Answer (score 1):

`writeUnShared()` still write a `null` into its `handlers` which'll grow as you write more object. that's the reason you got OOM on `readUnShared`.

check this: [OutOfMemoryException : Memory leak in the java class ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream](http://wordpress.nejaa-den.com/outofmemoryexception-memory-leak-in-the-java-class-objectoutputstream-and-objectinputstream/)