# Unset instance when have few memory

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a method that create some heavy objects *as cache*. This objects are rarely accessed, but expensive and slow to process, and are initialized only *on demand*. Then on use my application, for instance, I could request about three heavy object like that, and reuse them, but too is possible that I run it once and it only occupy memory while I never use it anymore during a session.

My question is: is possible I define that an object is "*garbage collectable*", then in case of application requires more memory it unset this unused data?

I think that it should works something like that (pseudo-code):

```
private static MyInstance instance = null;

public static getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = calculate();
        GC.put(instance);
    }

    return instance;
}
```

I think that I can do it with some kind of Timer, then check from time to time, but I guess that Java should have something like that, to call only if memory is heavy used.

Comment: Is this optimization really necessary?  How much memory do they use?

Comment: You cannot push the object to be garbage collected. Garbage collection run on its own only when more memory is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Java offers [three types of indirect references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html) which are sensitive to memory usage.

A cache can use a [`SoftReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) that will be cleared before the process raises an `OutOfMemoryError`. As long as there is plenty of memory, however, the `SoftReference` will prevent its referent from being garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have a way to manually de-allocate memory (see [Memory Management in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466353/memory-management-in-java). However, it does have **automatic** garbage collection. This means that any object that has no references left in the program will be automatically removed. In your case, for example, if an `Instance` is no longer used (the function that used it returns, and no other references exist, or you overwrite the sole variable that stored a reference to the `Instance` with something else), that `Instance` will be garbage-collected.

There is **not**, however, any method of making the `Instance` disappear any faster than getting rid of references to it, and letting the garbage collector deal with it.

What I would suggest instead, for your application, is something like an LRU cache (see [How would you implement an LRU cache in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221525/how-would-you-implement-an-lru-cache-in-java)), which would restrict your memory usage to a set **number** of instances, which (depending on what exactly `Instance` is) would limit you to a set amount of memory used by `Instance`s.

If you wanted instead to allow any amount of memory to be used, but *not used for very long*, you could create a wrapper class for `Instance`, which implements your cache idea (only creates an `Instance` when called, if its current copy is `null`), but keeps a timer and sets its `Instance` to `null` after a given amount of time has expired without it being used.

Comment: Someone with more knowledge than I have about Java garbage-collection could add information as to whether, when a program is close to running out of memory, the garbage collector tries right then to find things to get rid of. Seems like the speed (relative to memory being used up) with which the garbage collector can be relied on to free up space is important in this context.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a proper cache implementation. There are tons of them in Java, e.g., [Guava Cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained), which is highly configurable.

Your `calculate` method is just [CacheLoader#load](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html#load(K)).

You don't need to care about the GC. Just size your cache properly so that not too much memory gets used. Evicted cache entries get collected automaticaly (when not referenced elsewhere).

> I think that I can do it with some kind of Timer, then check from time to time, but I guess that Java should have something like that, to call only if memory is heavy used.

You can use time based eviction with e.g. `CacheBuilder#expireAfterWrite`. There's no caching in Java itself, but there's [SoftReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html). Anyway, I don't recommend using it directly, but consider using it with `CacheBuilder#softKeys`.