# Android app service memory usage issues

Tags: android

My android app's service uses 2.9 MB and nearly 5 MB when there is a notification?

Whether it's good or I should cut down on memory usage?

Can someone tell me the ways to cut down on memory usage?

Comment: I am just trying out on what are the ways to reduce memory usage whether there are any standard ways to reduce memory usage..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always advisable that your code use optimal memory.

Though this might give you idea about memory state in an app. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass

To go on statistic, in general its 24M.

> Whether it's good or I should cut down on memory usage?

Of course why not if its possible.

> Can someone tell me the ways to cut down on memory usage?

This is discussed here [What are some Java memory management best practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627784/what-are-some-java-memory-management-best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

Memory is a very precious resource in Android, proper management of Heap Space is very important as the heap size for an Android app can be as low as 16MB (HTC G1).

- Use logcat effectively to monitor if there are any memory leaks.
- Use WeakReference/SoftReference to allow GC to collect more objects (more efficiently).
- Use tools like MAT (for eclipse) to pin point leaks.

Read more about [these here](http://codelog.dexetra.com/getting-around-android-memory-blues).