# Best way to learn software optimization

Tags: java, performance, optimization

I want to learn software optimization, especially in Java. I want to be able to write code that's fast, and performs the best possible way. Can you point me to some resources to learn this? Books, tutorials, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Here a few links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627784/what-are-some-java-memory-management-best-practices http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26437/book-recommendation-for-java-good-practices

Comment: Nothing beats practice.  I suggest you try to optimise a program to see if it can perform better. Try using a profiler, micro-benchmarks, load tests on your program and see what you can improve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to read [Effective Java Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)

[image]