# Assigning an Object to null is a code smell. Consider refactoring

Tags: java

I'm Getting this Comment from PMD.But i have to empty the data.Is there any way to remove the content of that Object.

Comment: It would probably help if you posted the part of the code that is reported by PMD.

Comment: Can you not `dispose` of the object?

Comment: ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615419/could-someone-explaining-the-reasoning-behind-some-of-these-pmd-rules

Comment: It is highly likely that you don't "need to empty the data".

Comment: @Peter Lawrey : Thanks for that :) At least I learnt something here ;)

Comment: BTW what do you mean by "I have to empty the data" ?

Answer (score 2):

Setting a variable to null just removes a reference to the object.  it does not change the actual object.

If you need to clean up, you most likely need to do actions to the object referenced by your variable instead.

Comment: then how to change the object value..At last  i placed myStringobject = ''; instead of mystringObject = null;Then the errors were went.

Comment: @jayavardhan, for the record:  When you or PMD have problems with code, then _SHOW_ the code when asking here to get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning an object reference the value `null` does not 'empty the data'; it merely sets that variable reference to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It probably wants you to use the [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Comment: FWIW, the object might simply have been instantiated prematurely. Just fixed one such case.

Answer (score 0):

Just set your variable to `final`.

For instance, if there is the following code, SONAR will report as a code smell:

```
private Object obj = null;
```

However, if you just add final, it can be resolved.

```
private final Object obj = null;
```