# DD/DU warnings from PMD

Tags: java, pmd, dataflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the reason for these PMD rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615419/what-is-the-reason-for-these-pmd-rules)

Why do I get DD/DU warnings?

Here's my code:

```
// DD warning from PMD
public Object foo() {
  Object result = null;
  if (condition) {
    // code block, no accec to result
    result = newResult;
  }
  return result;
}
// DU warning from PMD
List<Object> data = new ArrayList<Object>(anotherList);
anotherList.remove(1);
// some other modification of anotherList
if (condition) {
  // some code. no access to data
  for (Object o : data) {
    // loop for original content of the list
  }
}
```

Is there something wrong here? Or is it a PMD bug? Can I ignore these warnings?

Answer (score 4):

Your DD anomaly can indeed be written better, with less chance of bugs:

```
return condition? newResult : null;
```

or, if you are more conservative regarding syntax,

```
if (condition)
  return newResult;
return null;
```

In the second example you are creating `data` unconditionally, but using it only conditionally. Rewrite to

```
if (condition) {
  List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>(anotherList);
  // or maybe just use anotherList without copying
  ...
}
else {
  anotherList.remove(1);
  // some other modifications of anotherList
}
```

Comment: First proposal for DD anomaly cannot be implemented because newResult is computed in the block. Second - provokes another PMD rule voilation (multiple exit from method).
Proposal for DU causes code duplication.

Comment: I'll take your word for it; it's not part of your question. Anyway, this answers your question: it is not a bug with PMD.