# Dataflow anomaly analysis warnings from PMD

Tags: java, pmd, dataflow, anomaly-detection

I am using Eclipse with the `PMD Plug-in (4.0.0.v20130510-1000)` and get a lot of those violations:

`Found 'DD'-anomaly for variable 'freq' (lines '187'-'189').`
`Found 'DU'-anomaly for variable 'freq' (lines '189'-'333').`

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1615477/1137043) SO answer, it says that those anomalies are related to assigning values that are never read. But I get the violations for instance in this case:

```
// here I get a DD anomaly
double freq = 0;
try {
  // here I get a DU anomaly
  freq = Double.parseDouble(getFrequencyTextField().getText());
} catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
  Log.e(e.getMessage());
}
if (freq < 10E6) doSomething();
```

If I remove the initialization and add a `freq = 0;` line in the `catch` block, the DD anomaly vanishes, but I get a DU anomaly on both the assignments.

**Now my question: How am I supposed to deal with that? What would be the preferred solution of PMD? And what exactly is this rule trying to prevent (i.e. why is it bad practice)?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
double freq; // (1)
try {
  // here I get a DU anomaly
  freq = Double.parseDouble(getFrequencyTextField().getText());
} catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
  Log.e(e.getMessage());
  freq = 0; // (2)
}
if (freq < 10E6) doSomething();
```

The first problem is that in the catch the parseDouble assignment is not done to freq.
On an exception freq still would be 0. *Maybe flaggable.*
So it goes away when assigning to freq inside catch.

When assigning to freq in the catch, (2), the inital assignment, (1), would never be read, so only a declaration suffices.

With respect to better style:

```
try {
  // here I get a DU anomaly
  double freq = Double.parseDouble(getFrequencyTextField().getText());

  if (freq < 10E6) doSomething();
  ...

} catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
  Log.e(e.getMessage());
}
```

Or follow the answer of @JoachimSauer, using a double conversion that does not throw an exception. The logging would indicate a level of seriousness in preference of the above style. Logging inside a simple conversion function on error might not be good style: too much logging, ignored logging (?), hard to repair.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that cleared up things for me. Also thanks for the suggestion. I always appreciate code style corrections. (That's why I started using PMD in the first place.)

Answer (score 4):

You could get around this problem (and separate concerns a bit more clearly) by extracting the parsing into a separate method:

```
double freq = parseDouble(getFrequencyTextField().getText());

// later in the class (or in a utility class):

public static double parseDouble(final String input) {
  try {
    return Double.parseDouble(input);
  } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
    Log.e(e.getMessage());
    return 0;
  }
}
```

And if you have different default values, you could also add a two-argument version: `public static double parseDouble(final String input, final double defaultValue)`.

Comment: I like the default value idea. I think I am going to do that. Although in that example, I just get the next PMD violation: `A method should have only one exit point, and that should be the last statement in the method`.

Comment: @brimborium: that warning creates an ugly semantic loop: I see no (simple) solution to avoid *both* warnings at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, I am inclined to kick that second rule out of the ruleset. Although I understand it's point. It is much easier to understand the full meaning of a complex method if there is only one exit point...

Comment: Personally I don't agree with the one-exit-point rule at all. It often makes the code needlessly complicated. I'd replace it with a "don't-have-exit-points-at-unexpected-places" rule, but that *might* be slightly harder to check for a static analyzer ;-)

Comment: A return in a catch block is always bad. Add a finally block and you have confusing code.

Comment: @BevynQ: I disagree. Sometimes a return in the catch is exactly what you intend to do (such as in this case). A return in a `final` however, is pure evilk.